# html dialog element is covering up invisible recaptcha challenge popup. how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

https://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/agbPYJ
access the example in incognito mode, click "open" button to open the sample signin form, then click "Sign Up" button to trigger the challenge. 
I am not sure if its a not fixable problem with using recaptcha inside dialog or its more of a fixable thing with some sort of hack of css and html? Tried z-index on the dialog, that did not work at all..

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container my-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2 class="text-center mb-4">
          Sign Up Form with Google reCAPTCHA
        </h2>
        <dialog ref="mydialog">
          <form
              method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input 
                   type="email" 
                   name="email" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Enter your e-mail address"
                   required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input 
                   type="password" 
                   name="password" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Enter your password"
                   required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <vue-recaptcha
              ref="recaptcha"
              size="invisible"
              :sitekey="sitekey"
              @verify="register"
              @expired="onCaptchaExpired"
            />
            <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                    @click="validate">
              Sign Up
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </dialog>
        <button @click="openDialog">open</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  components: { VueRecaptcha },

  data () {
    return {
      email: null,
      password: null,
      recaptchaToken: null,
      sitekey: '6Lfe33gUAAAAAMCuDwRfhSUV4sGkqGDaGrKqjkmZ'
    }
  },

  methods: {
    openDialog() {
      this.$refs.mydialog.showModal();
    },
    register () {
      // make post request to the server
    },

    validate () {
      // if validate true exec recaptcha
      this.$refs.recaptcha.execute()
    },

    onCaptchaExpired () {
      this.$refs.recaptcha.reset()
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So heres the thing:

If you use `<dialog></dialog>` it is hidden by default.

Either use `<dialog open></dialog>`to show the dialog on startup, 
or open the dialog via some js:

```
// Update button opens a modal dialog
    updateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.showModal();
    });
```

> HOWEVER. the dialog element is not very widly supported, so I would
>   really advise you NOT to use it.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog

You should therefor change

`<dialog class="my-dialog"></dialog>`

to

`<div class="my-dialog"></div>`

You should then see it in in all Browsers, and this is the supported way of doing it.

Comment: yes, I know. I wonder if there is way to solve it, without switching from dialog to other elements though?

Comment: @Ezeewei I updated my answer! Please not that `dialog` element is not suppurted very widly so I would really discourage you to use it